# How many dataweave scripts in .dwl files can a transform processor run concurrently?

Tags: mule, dataweave

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdQS5.jpg

is it possible to run multiple data weave scripts concurrently using the same transform processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't run concurrently they run one after the other.

Comment: In that case, what would be the sequence of execution of scripts?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as they are all executed under the same input

Comment: Your scripts should not depend on the order of execution.

Comment: thanks, @machaval and @ Alejandro Dobniewski
Is there any constrain on which all scripts are allowed to use the input payload? Are different scripts allowed only to work on different variables?